# Question about a marked poisson point process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Q) Let runners arrive on an infinitely long track with a mean density of 1 per meter. No two runners stand at the same place and the number of runners standing in any two disjoint segments are independent of each other. All the runners run, independently, an exponentially distributed random distance with mean $20m$. Prove that the resulting runner locations has the same distribution as before.

I know that the number of runners in a length $l$, follow $\sim Pois(l)$ distribution and each runner is given a mark(i.e. the distance they run) and that a marked Poisson process is also a Poisson process but not sure how to translate "resulting runner locations has the same distribution as before" into an equation? Is it the joint distribution of the runner locations?

Comment: One way to prove this is, indeed, to consider the point process $N(dx,dl) = \sum_{i\ge 1} \delta_{(X_i,L_i)} (dx,dl)$, where $X_i$ is $i$th runner location and $L_i$ is the distance she ran. This is a Poisson point process with intensity $dx\times \nu(dl)$, where $\nu$ is the distribution of distance (it does not have to be exponential, not even positive). Then you have to prove that $M(dx) = \sum_{i\ge 1} \delta_{X_i+L_i} (dx)$ is again a Poisson point process with intensity $dx$. This follows rather straightforwardly from $M(A) = N(\{(x,l): x+l\in A\})$.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks, I can see that $M(A)$ is the number of points whose $x+l\in A$ but may I know how that implies $M(dx)$ is a Poisson point process with intensity $dx$?

Comment: Denoting $F_A = \{(x,l): x+l\in A\}$, for disjoint $A_n$, $n\ge 1$, the sets $F_{A_n}$ are disjoint as well, and $F_{\bigcup_n A_n} = \bigcup_n F_{A_n}$. So $M$ inherits all the properties of a random measure (PPP). You only have to compute the intensity, which is rather straightforward.